# 3D molde rendering SDK for Windows 8 store application in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, 3d, winrt-xaml

I want to develop windows store 8 application which render 3D model.

Is there any SDK available for 3D model rendering in windows store 8 application using c#?

i want to develop application simmiler to this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=R6pbnVsUvpM

i have 3D model i just capture image and identify 3D model and render it and perform action like 360 view etc.

any suggestion what is the best solution for that ?

Comment: can you please check for my updated question ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this projects [Visual-Studio-3D-Starter-Kit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-3D-Starter-455a15f1), [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or look at this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/11/20/building-windows-store-apps-with-net.aspx) on section **Writing Windows Store DirectX Games -- SharpDX**